# ExtJs Charts with time axis, update problem

Tags: charts, extjs4

I'm using Ext4 js to create charts.
My charts are line charts showing evolution of events during time, so my bottom axes is a time axes:

```
    {
    type: 'Time',
    position: 'bottom',
    grid: grid,
    fields: 'name',
    title: false,
    dateFormat: 'd/m/y',
    groupBy: 'year,month,day',

    aggregateOp: 'sum',
    label: {
        orientation: 'horizontal',
        rotate: {
            degrees: label_rotation
        }
    }
```

I have links to change the scale.
Clicking on one of those link should change dateformat and groupby options.
Here the code:

```
scaleGroups = {
    'DAY': {
    dateFormat: 'd/m/y',
        groupBy: 'year,month,day' 
    },
    'MONTH' :{
            dateFormat: 'M Y',
            groupBy: 'year,month'
    },
    'YEAR' :{
            dateFormat: 'Y',
            groupBy: 'year'
    }
};


function changeChartScale(chart_id, scale) {
    var chart = Ext.getCmp(chart_id);
    var axis = chart.axes.get(1);
    selectedGroup = scaleGroups[scale];
    axis.dateFormat = selectedGroup.dateFormat;
    axis.groupBy = selectedGroup.groupBy;

    chart.redraw();
}
```

The problem is that changing from a scale to another, for example from days to months, previous labels remain. So the line is correct, but I see both day labels and month labels.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance,
Sabrina

**UPDATE 07/06/2011**:
The same code on a sample html page, importing only this javascript library, works.

Maybe it's a problem of compatibility with other javascript libraries I use (Jquery, googlempas...).
Did anyone experience the same problem?

Answer (score 5):

I found a workaround since the chart.redraw() method doesn't automatically redraw the axis scale/values.

Set a new maximum for the axes, then use the axis.drawAxis() method prior to redrawing the chart...

My chart redraws when the user sorts a column on a bound grid.

```
    chart.axes.items[0].fields = [column.dataIndex];
    chart.series.items[0].yField = [column.dataIndex];


    var s = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('myStore');
    var max = s.max(column.dataIndex);


    chart.axes.items[0].maximum = max;
    chart.axes.items[0].drawAxis();


    chart.redraw();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a Sencha bug!

This is still unanswered on their forum:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?145433-ExtJS-4-chart-store-update-issue

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a fix! Just set minimum and maximum property in axes to a reasonable values (ie: per days set 31, per months set 12). It works for me!